# Calculate relative percentage (ratio) for groups in a dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r

I have an example dataframe as follows. I cannot supply the real dataframe since it's confidential:

```
Sex Country Voted
0   USA     0
0   USA     1
1   USA     1
1   USA     0
```

Sex 0 = Male, 1 = Female

Voted 0 = Didn't vote, 1 = Did vote

I have performed the following operation on the dataframe:

```
df %>%
   group_by(Sex, Country, Voted) %>%
   summarise(n = n())
```

Which gives the following (example) output:

```
Sex Country Voted N
0   USA     0     300
1   USA     0     200
0   USA     1     100
1   USA     1     400
0   UK      0     200
1   UK      0     300
0   UK      1     250
1   UK      1     250
```

I am now trying to calculate the relative percentage; the aim is to calculate how many people of **each sex** in **each country** have voted (or didn't vote). So, for example, the percentage of males voting in the USA is 100/400 = 25%, because we have a total of 400 males in the USA. It is not 100/1000 (the total number of people from the USA in the sample) and it is not 100/2000 (the total sample size).

What is the fastest way to calculate this? I tried to use `prop.table`, but it tells me:

`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :`

`only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

I am not prepared to change the `Country` variable to numeric since I have more than 50 countries in the dataframe (the part shown here in the question was just an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As after `summarise` one grouping level is dropped ideally, the following should give you the output.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Sex, Country, Voted) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n))
  #If you need the values in percentage 
  #mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
df <- data.frame(Sex=c(0,1,0,1), Country=rep("USA", 4),
                 Voted=c(0,0,1,1), N=c(300,200,100,400),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(Country, Sex, Voted) %>% 
  spread(Voted, N) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = (`1`/(`0` + `1`)))

#   Sex Country   0   1     ratio
# 1   0     USA 300 100 0.2500000
# 2   1     USA 200 400 0.6666667
```